# Not showing icon app in Android 9.0 Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, package

I using library https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_launcher_icons run icon app. I also try `flutter pub pub get` and `flutter pub pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main` but in Android 9.0, I'm not found icon app which I using but only see the default flutter icon. How to fix it?

Comment: Can you post your pubspec.yaml file code? It would help in answering your question.

Comment: @Siddharth Patankar My pubspec.yaml file look like this:
dev_dependencies:

  `flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.0

  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter_icons:
  image_path: "icon/icon.png"
  android: true
  ios: true`

Do you see where it is wrong?

Comment: I was facing the same problem. After restarting the device the proper launcher icon was shown.